# Jenkins : Setting global string parameter

Tags: jenkins

I would like to set the EmailAddress field which is part of my jenkins jobs as a Global String Parameter in the System Configuration and then use it in my job.

When I 'Build with Parameters', the default value of EmailAddress field shows as "${Email}" because Email is the environment variable I have set in System Configuration.

My question is :

I would like to see the actual default values(ex; "xyz@abc.com,jkm@abc.com") so that I can edit the values if I like. Is there a possible way to do the same while using the Global String Parameter?

Comment: Possibly using a parameter plugin. For instance, [extensible choice plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extensible-choice-parameter/) allows you to define a global choice. If you define a list with only a single value and make the parameter editable, you effectively show a default value which can be edited.